# Sort map by weekdays in dart

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, maps

I am having a Map of weekdays and timings. But I am unable to sort it according to weekdays so Monday comes first and then the following. Here is my map example. I tried **SplayTreeMap** but I could not make it work.

```
  Map<String, dynamic> onlineVideoAppointment = {
  'Mon': '12:00 AM-12:30 AM',
  'Wed': '12:15 AM-1:15 AM',
  'Sun': '12:00 AM-1:00 AM',
  'Thu': '12:30 AM-1:30 AM',
  'Tue': '12:15 AM-1:15 AM',
  'Fri': '12:30 AM-1:00 AM',
  'Sat': '12:00 AM-12:30 AM'
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to have fun with this and solved it with iterable functions. Here's a runnable sample:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> onlineVideoAppointment = {
  'Mon': '12:00 AM-12:30 AM',
  'Wed': '12:15 AM-1:15 AM',
  'Sun': '12:00 AM-1:00 AM',
  'Thu': '12:30 AM-1:30 AM',
  'Tue': '12:15 AM-1:15 AM',
  'Fri': '12:30 AM-1:00 AM',
  'Sat': '12:00 AM-12:30 AM'
};

enum Day { sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat }

extension DayX on Day {
  String stringify() {
    final clean = toString().substring(toString().indexOf('.') + 1);
    return '${clean[0].toUpperCase()}${clean.substring(1)}';
  }
}

void main() {
  final sorted = Day.values.map((day) => onlineVideoAppointment.entries.firstWhere((entry) => entry.key == day.stringify()));
  
  final sortedMap = Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterable(sorted, key: (appt) => appt.key, value: (appt) => appt.value);
  
  print(sortedMap);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me the way I wanted. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

A `SplayTreeMap` does sort by keys, but since your keys are `String`s, it would sort them alphabetically.  If you instead can use the [`DateTime.monday`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/monday-constant.html), `DateTime.tuesday`, etc. constants (which happen to already start from Monday) as the keys instead, then it would have the sort order you want.

If you must use `String`-based keys, then you just need to provide an easy to way to convert from `String`s to the constants and provide a proper comparison function:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

Map<String, String> onlineVideoAppointment = {
  'Mon': '12:00 AM-12:30 AM',
  'Wed': '12:15 AM-1:15 AM',
  'Sun': '12:00 AM-1:00 AM',
  'Thu': '12:30 AM-1:30 AM',
  'Tue': '12:15 AM-1:15 AM',
  'Fri': '12:30 AM-1:00 AM',
  'Sat': '12:00 AM-12:30 AM'
};

const dayAbbreviationToValue = {
  'Mon': DateTime.monday,
  'Tue': DateTime.tuesday,
  'Wed': DateTime.wednesday,
  'Thu': DateTime.thursday,
  'Fri': DateTime.friday,
  'Sat': DateTime.saturday,
  'Sun': DateTime.sunday,
};

void main() {
  var sortedMap = SplayTreeMap.of(
      onlineVideoAppointment,
      (key1, key2) => dayAbbreviationToValue[key1]!
          .compareTo(dayAbbreviationToValue[key2]!));

  for (var entry in sortedMap.entries) {
    print('${entry.key}: ${entry.value}');
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this code it says undefined "dayNameToValue".

Comment: @UsmanAkhlaq Oops, that was a typo from a last-minute edit I made to the code.  Corrected now.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. Both will certainly get the job done. This one is a little less *home-made*.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still need help on such case, try to manually assign digit to the days, and sort them by the field you have assigned the digit to.